# How to check cidr value is valid or not

Tags: perl, ip, cidr

I am reading CIDR values from the text file, once reading list of CIDR values. I have to validate the CIDR value whether it is valid one or not. How can i Validate the CIDR value is correct or not.
For example when I try with 148.64.0.0/224 CIDR value in following website (i.e https://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr) it is showing as  "Invalid CIDR format".
Can you please provide sample snippet code in perl language to validate the CIDR value?

I tried to validate with whois website, but it did not work.

Comment: /224 is invalid as no IP4 address has more than 32 bits. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Might wanna check out Wikipedia's article on the basics of CIDR if you're going to implement something that's supposed to check CIDR addresses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing

Comment: A quick search on metacpan found [this module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::net::CIDR) among others.

Answer (score 1):

You could use https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Works::Network for this.  If the network is not valid, an exception will be thrown.  You can trap the exception and then decide how you want to handle it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::Works::Network ();
use Try::Catch qw( catch try );

my $network;
try {
    $network
        = Net::Works::Network->new_from_string( string => '148.64.0.0/224' );
}
catch {
    print "Not a valid network: $_\n";
};

# ... maybe do something with $network here
```

Answer (score 1):

`Net::Works::Network` would not compile for me on Strawberry Perl (Windows). I used `Net::CIDR` instead.

```
use Net::CIDR;

foreach my $ip (@ips) { 

  ####validate IP (or CIDR range). if invalid, returns undef
  my $result = Net::CIDR::cidrvalidate($ip);

  if ($result eq "") {
    print "\nbad IP or CIDR range: $ip";
    next;
  }

}
```